# Java arraylist indexof

Tags: java, arraylist, indexing

Here is my class `animals.java`:

```
public class animals {
    String Name, ID;
    static ArrayList<animals> animalData = new ArrayList<animals>();

    public animals(){}
    public animals(String name, String id){
        super();
        this.Name = name;
        this.ID = id;
    }

    public void addAnimal(String name, String id){
        animalData.add(new animals(name, id));
    }

    public int search(String name){
        return this.animalData.indexOf(name);
    }
}
```

When I add an animal name with an id it works normally, but when I use search method I saw only -1. Maybe I try override method `equals` or `indexof` in this class? help me for this

Thank you and sorry for my bad english..

Comment: Yes, you need to override the equals method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are adding instances of `animals` to the list. You are searching for the instance by name.  Since `animalData` does not contain any instances of `String`, `indexOf()` will never return an index.

If you want to access an instance of `animals` by the name, you should use a `Map<String,animals>`.

```
Map<String,animals> animalMap = new HashMap<String,animals>();
animalMap.put("Mat", new animals("Mat", "id");
animals animal = animalMap.get("Mat");
```

The proper use of `indexOf()` is to pass in an instance that is equal to an instance already in the collection. As others have pointed out, this will require you to define `equals()` to define what makes two instances equal. You should also override `hashcode()` when you override `equals()` because there is an assumed correlation.

*Note*: The convention is to use CapitalCase for class names. Also, the class name should not be plural. You will have many instances of `Animal`, you may later make a class that is a collection of `Aniamal`s, but that should not be the name of the main class.

Comment: ty but i want to learn this question;
static ArrayList<animals> animalData = new ArrayList<animals>();

i can add the list new animals for example: "CAT", "1";   "DOG", "2" .. this work normally and i show all item but;

when i want to search "CAT" in animalData list i want to get "CAT"'s index.( Because i need **index**, when i change "CAT" > "BIRD")
animalData .set(**index**, element); i know this method but i need "CAT" index.

it's impossible?

Comment: @user1429570: Do you mean you want to access "CAT" based on the `ID` you define? Or do you want to access it by the index the instance exists in the list? `indexOf()` will give you the index of the instance in the list. It will __not__ search the list for the instance with the name "CAT" and return to you the id you assigned of "1"; If you want to do the later, you should make a map of string to string and use name as the key and id as the value.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you need to override `equals()` and `hashcode()` methods when you use objects in collections and perform lookup based on object.

`indexOf()` returns object because it just returns object at that perticular index. But, when you do object based lookup, if equals() and `hashCode()` are not overridden, `equals()` may fail and you get unpredictable results.

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? Can you update question with your equals() and hashcode() methods?

Comment: @user1429570: See this link for more information http://www.technofundo.com/tech/java/equalhash.html

Comment: If you have problem with equals/hashcode AND using eclipse, click `Source -> Generate hashCode() & equals()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to define an "equals" method

Comment: Just having equlas() may not be valid hashcode/equals override contract.

Comment: when i define equals method its default code how i change i dont know :s

Comment: you probably want something like public boolean equals(Object b) { return ( id.equals(b)); }

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a String...
You'd better use a HashMap I think...

But yeah you have to change your structure(which isn't very efficient)

Comment: How is a HashMap any less efficent?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I would use:

```
public class animals {
    String Name, ID;
    static Map<String, animals> animalData = new HashMap<String, animals>();

    public animals(){}
    public animals(String name, String id){
        super();
        this.Name = name;
        this.ID = id;
    }

    public static void addAnimal(String name, String id){
        animalData.add(new animals(name, id));
    }

    // Returns null if no registered animal has this name.
    public animals search(String name){
        return this.animalData.get(name);
    }
}
```

This way, you make the `search` method much faster (O(1)), you don't need to override the `equals` method anymore.

Note that if `animalData` is static, you should consider to make `addAnimal()` static as well since it's sort of a 'setter' for `aniamalData`.